# What problem could be happening in case AWS VPN is up but ping is not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, network-programming, vpn

Im trying to set up a AWS Site to Site VPN connection with an external partner.

What I did so far

1 - Created Customer Gateway and Virtual Private Gateway

2 - Created VPN connection

3 - External partner made the configuration on their side and the VPN is up

4 - Add External partner IPs in static routes

5 - Add External partner IPs in route table and associated with the subnets

6 - Add External partner IPs in the EC2 security group

But when I try to ping the external partner IP I have no answer

External Partner says their firewall is allowing my IPs

What could else I can do to troubleshoot this problem ?

[EDIT] External Partner pings our IP and it works but the other way does not work

Comment: Note that ping is neither TCP nor UDP but ICMP. Often that's overlooked when configuring firewall rules / security groups. Or, it may even be intentional. (Ping is blocked to EC2 instances by default too.) It's possible that ping is blocked but the actual services that you need are accessible anyway, did you try?

Comment: Nice note but I tried to access with another protocols and same way I receive timeout. Do you know if there is a way to check any logs from VPC / VPN Site to Site? Because my concern is trying to change some configuration in my side when the true problem is in external partner configuration. How can I guaranteee that the problem is on their side ?

Comment: Hi! The external partner can ping our instance from theirs. But the other way (we ping their) does not work. It could be possible with some firewall of them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External Partner noticed that was a problem in their firewall. In the end, the problem it was on their side